# vscode php class methods hint (ctrl + space) is present?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I want to know if in visual studio code the ctrl + space feature for classes written by me is supported or only for standard php functions

If it is present, there is something to activate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. There is a plugin for vscode called Crane PHP Intellisense